# How to get login/password from Google account password manager android app?

Tags: android

At my app I have login page. This app is made from web service at which I also was registered. I would like to get saved password+login from my Google account for preventing long and boring typing. Maybe Google have some special API for that or I can use some built-in methods? I know that on this source I have to add some my attempts or results of search, but I didn't manage to find any suitable link which could help me, so I hope that you will help me in that question :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. You can take benefit of Autofill Framework of android.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="password" />
```

If you enable autofillHints options for username and password, android will automatically fill saved username and passwords.

Comment: no, I would like to do some another thing - you have Google account for example and you use a lot of services in the Internet, and for one service you decided to make your own app, for logging in to the service you have to use login+password which are saved at pass storage of your Google account, I would like to get saved password+login

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate Google account single sign-on, you can follow the instruction in this link for your app
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

It allows users to sign in to your app with their google account.

Comment: will I be able to get one single password and one single login from my google account, not login to my main Google account, only get saved password?

Comment: The purpose of single sign-on is to let users securely authenticate with multiple applications by only logging once, in this case their Google account in the phone. "Securely" here means that you cannot get their password, otherwise, it is a security breach right?

Comment: let see and example - you have Facebook app at your phone and you have Facebook account, and when you are logging to Facebook app you can see suggestion of autocomplete, I would like to create smth like that

Comment: Facebook can do that because they store their user's username and password in their database! Now you want to get username and password from another service in this case Google, I don't think that is possible mate. The best you can do is to apply single sign-on

Answer (score 1):

Use Google SmartLock SDK to save password for that app. Check their documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/

Comment: and I will be able to get password+login for the certain service?

Comment: This SDK is used to save & retrive password+login. Please read the documentation you will get more info.

Comment: I have read it, but I can't understand how to get password+login for the certain service, maybe I have to enter web address for this service at my request?

Comment: Please read this documentation to retrive user credentials 

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials